# Change numbers to characters with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to convert a string to incorporate hyphens (-) between words and change to lowercase. For example:

- From `'ThisIsMyString'` to `'this-is-my-string'`

This is my code so far:

```
def kebabize(str)
 str.gsub(/(?=[A-Z])/, '-').downcase
end
```

I also need it to remove numbers from the string. Example:

- From `'ThereIs3Words'` to `'there-is-words'`

What do I need to add to the code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap another `gsub` around it:

```
def kebabize(str)
 str.gsub(/\d+/, '').gsub(/(?=[A-Z])/, '-').downcase
end
```

Comment: Agree with the use of `\d+` deleted my answer in favour of this one.

Answer (score -1):

The regex to capture this with is [A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z]|\b)
See: https://regex101.com/r/popMSp/1

Explanation:
read 'word' starting with capital ([A-Z]), followed by several undercase letters ([a-z]+), until you encounter uppercase letter [A-Z] or \b

In code you leave out the boundary option, because this doesn't need to be replaced:

```
def addMinus(str)
  str.gsub(/([A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z]))/, "\\1-")
end

print addMinus('ThisIsMyString'), "\n"
```

Comment: Like @Jan, even if you appreciate a different solution more than mine, there's no need to downvote a perfect valid solution. And if you do, let us know why, so we can all benefit from your opinion/knowledge.